# Show that there exists two Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ such that $[P:P\cap Q] = [Q:P\cap Q] = p$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let G be a group with the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups different from 1 mod $p^2$.  Show that there exists two Sylow $p$-subgroups $P$ and $Q$ such that $[P:P\cap Q] = [Q:P\cap Q] = p$.

First, from the problem formulation, there are at least two (distinct) Sylow p-subgroups since they must exist and there cannot be only one.  Call them $P$ and $Q$.  Let $S$ be the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups.  All Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, so $P$ acts on $S$ by conjugation.  Write $S$ as the union of $s$ disjoint orbits under this action, $S = O_1 \cup O_2 \cup \dots \cup O_s$.  Let $P_i$ be a representative of $O_i$.  Then $|O_i| = [P:P_i \cap P]$.  $P$ will be a representative of one of the orbits, say $O_1$, so $|O_1|= [P:P \cap P] = 1$.  Thus $Q$ is a representative of a different orbit, say $O_2$, and $|O_2| = [P:P \cap Q] \equiv 0 \mod p$.  Similarly, considering that $Q$ acts on $S$ by conjugation, $[Q:P \cap Q] \equiv 0 \mod p$.

I think the key is to bring in that $n_p$ is different from $1 \mod p^2$, but I have not yet figured out how.  Am I on the right track?  Or does anyone have any hints?

Comment: When $P$ acts on $S$ by conjugation, wouldn't the stabilizer of an element $P_i$ be equal to $N_G(P_i)\cap P$? Your formula for the size of the orbit seems incorrect to me.

Comment: Which are the orders $\bmod p^2$ of the orbits other than $\{P\}$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: It is correct, because $N_G(P_i) \cap P = P_i \cap P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track Steve. Note that the orbit sizes you wrote down are almost correct: $|O_i| = index[P_i:N_P(P_i)]$ - note the index $i$ in the first $P_i$ here. But it is not difficult to show that in fact $N_P(P_i)= P \cap P_i$ (let $x \in P \cap N_G(P_i)$, then $<x>P_i$ is a $p$-subgroup containing the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P_i$. But then $<x>P_i = P_i$, that is $x \in P_i$).

So the $i$-th orbit size is $|P_i:P \cap P_i|$. And observe that $|P_i:P \cap P_i|= |P:P \cap P_i|$ ($|PP_i|=|P||P_i|/|P\cap P_i|)$ and this number is a power of $p$. If $P \neq P_i$, then $|P:P \cap P_i| > 1$.

Now assume that, except for the orbit $O_1$, which is $P$ itself, all other orbits are in size larger or equal than $p^2$. It follows, taking the sizes mod $p^2$ in $S = O_1 \cup O_2 \cup \dots \cup O_s$ that, $|S| = n_p = |O_1| = 1$ mod $p^2$, contradicting your assumption. Hence there must be an orbit of size $p$, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  As noted, I did skip a couple steps with the order of the orbits.  I seem to be missing something at the end though.  What if $|O_I|

Comment: Thanks for helping.  As noted, I did skip a couple steps with the order of the orbits.  I seem to be missing something at the end though.  What if $|O_i| =p^3$.  Can we necessarily say that there is an orbit of size $p$?  (Sorry for double posting.  LaTeX seems difficult on a tablet.)

Comment: If all orbits have order $p^3$ (except for $O_1$), then $n_p = 1$ mod $p^2$. If you mean that *some* orbit has order $p^3$, then given your assumptions there must still be some other orbit having size $p$.

Comment: I see it now.  I was making a careless mistake.  Thanks again.